# How to grant root privilages to an user in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

how do give full permissions to the normal user in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please describe what problem you are trying to solve. The solution should NEVER be to give root privileges. For running single commands with raised privileges, you can use `sudo`.

Comment: I want to give rwx permisiion to the file in /dev/ directory . using chmod i am able to do that but after resart of pc once again i have to do chmod .  i want to give the permission permanantly.

Comment: Why does a normal need rwx in /dev ? That's normally only system processes that need that. You dont want a user to be able to write directly to a disk-device or other system resource. So, EXACTLY what are your requirement ?

Comment: I have installed one driver for the device . so that driver is working only after the full permission to that device file in dev directory.

Comment: which device? Which /dev/? exactly. which driver?  Please clarify it. Maybe it is possible to solve your problem with adding your user to the right group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very dangerous for system's stability to work as root in GUI mode as it was in Windows XP.

> If you have a user you want to give all admin privileges to, the best
>   method is to simply add that user to the admin group. You will notice
>   this line, in the `/etc/sudoers` file:
>
> ```
> %admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
> ```
>
> This means all members of the admin group have full sudo privileges.
>   To add your user to the admin group, you would issue the command (as a
>   user who already has full sudo privileges):
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -a -G sudo USERNAME
> ```
>
> Where USERNAME is the name of the user to be added. Once the user logs
>   out and logs back in, they will now enjoy full sudo privileges.

[Reference](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-quickly-give-users-sudo-privileges-in-linux/)

To run an app with full admin privileges, just type `sudo` before a command:

```
sudo app
```

You will need to enter your USERNAME's password. System remembers this password for some time, so consequent commands you'll run without password inputing for some time.

Note: password you'll be typing will not be visible in terminal

Answer (score 2):

You can use the /etc/sudoers.tmp file to modify the user permissions

First with root user:

```
sudo -i
```

run the following command to lead you to the /etc/sudoers.tmp folder

```
visudo
```

in the nano screen navigate down to the section #User privilege specification
you can see that the root user have this privilege specifications

```
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

you can edit the **admin** user as the same format or add your user to the file
for example:

```
mehran ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

you can check if the user have permissions with the command

```
grep '^sudo' /etc/group
```

If the output was sudo:x:27:yourusername, then you granted the user root privileges.